# Grep matching two or more patterns within pattern file

Tags: regex, grep, gnu

I'd like to use grep to pull in matching patterns from a file only if the line contains two or more patterns contained within my pattern file. This is my rough idea of what the syntax looks like, but it doesn't work. Any pointers?

```
egrep -f -i pattern.txt {2,} file.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain what was your reasoning behind this *rough idea*?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in general — `grep` doesn't have such capabilities. I would rather try to tinker around the regexes from the pattern file — can you provide it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the source file, patterns, and the sample output you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '/pattern1/' -E '/pattern2/' file
```

In this way you can scan multiple pattern in a single line using this command. try to google 'regular expressions with grep tutorial' and you will find the answer. also be specific when mentioning the pattern you want to search in a line.